# Django: Querying a stacked inline object | ValueError at /profile Cannot query "Anthony_Jamez12": Must be "Profile" instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-admin

I am trying to make an Instagram Clone. So what I'm trying to do here is query the user's photos that were uploaded and display them on the frontend. When I query into the stacked inline Uploads model I can get the photos to display on the frontend, but not the photos that belong to the user (all the photos in database display on the frontend). I tried to figure out a way to get all the photo's to go to the extended user model, but I couldn't figure a way to do that. Basically I'm trying to get the images that the user uploaded and if anyone could help that would be much appreciated.

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = False, blank = True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True, blank = True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True, blank = True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True, blank = True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 50, null = True, blank = True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length = 300, null = True, blank = True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(default = 'default.png', upload_to = "img/%y", null = True, blank = True)
    #uploads = models.ForeignKey(Uploads, on_delete = models.CASCADE, default = None, null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

class Uploads(models.Model):
    caption = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to = "img/%y", blank=True, null = True)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete = models.CASCADE, default = None, null = True)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True, null = False)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.caption and str(self.image)
```

views.py

```
def profile(request):
    img = Uploads.objects.filter(profile_id = request.user)    #Here is my error and question
    #img = Uploads.objects.all()
    profile = Profile.objects.filter(user = request.user)
    context = {"profile": profile, "img": img}

    return render(request, "main/profile.html", context)
```

And here's a visual representation of the models if that helps understand what I am trying to get.
[image]

Comment: You are not passing any `profile_id` in parameter. Did you passed `profile_id` in `url` ?

Comment: Didn't it raise an `Error` when you open the page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def profile(request):
    img = Uploads.objects.filter(profile_id = request.user)
```

You are passing a User type object to *profile_id* which requires a *int* or if *profile* it requires a Profile object.
Change it to

```
profile = Profile.objects.filter(user = request.user)
img = Uploads.objects.filter(profile_id = profile.id)
context = {"profile": profile, "img": img}
```

OR

```
img = Uploads.objects.filter(profile__user = request.user)
profile = Profile.objects.filter(user = request.user)
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to PrOgRaMmEr and ABHISHEK TIWARI, this what I needed to change.

```
def profile(request):
    img = Uploads.objects.filter(profile_id = request.user.profile)
    profile = Profile.objects.filter(user = request.user)
    context = {"profile": profile, "img": img}

    return render(request, "main/profile.html", context)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like :-

```
def profile(request):
    img = Uploads.objects.filter(profile_id = request.user)
    #img = Uploads.objects.all()

# Changed this line
    profile = Profile.objects.filter(user = request.user.profile)
    context = {"profile": profile, "img": img}

    return render(request, "main/profile.html", context)
```